# SQL CONCAT cuts off last digits when connecting char with float

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've got a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1 (
    POS1 char(4),
    POS2 float)

INSERT INTO TABLE1 
    (POS1, POS2)
VALUES 
    ('6000', 4518.6082),
    ('6000', 3451.23),
    ('5000', 341);
```

**Table:**

```
POS1    POS2
6000    4518.6082
6000    3451.23
5000    341
```

I want to combine POS1 and POS2 with `CONCAT`:

```
SELECT CONCAT(rtrim(POS1),'_',rtrim(POS2)) AS POS1_POS2
FROM TABLE1
```

Unfortunately, I somehow "loose" digits (rounding). **Result:**

```
POS1_POS2
6000_4518.61
6000_3451.23
5000_341
```

It works quite well if I change float within the CREATE TABLE Statement to numeric(10,4). Is there any solution that works without changing the data type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using `format` function

```
SELECT CONCAT(rtrim(POS1), '_', rtrim(format(pos2, '#.####'))) AS POS1_POS2
FROM TABLE1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

> Is there a solution that works without changing the data type?

You clearly do not understand the difference between floats and decimals.  The values that you are storing are not exactly the values that you see.  Hence, the *correct* solution is to change the data type in the table.

`Format()` does fix the problem, particularly being able to eliminate the trailing zeros.  However, it is a total approximation and hence prone to error.

You should store the values as decimals -- because they *are* decimal values and not floating point values.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is, that the values are stored as floats in my application - although (as you say) they are decimals.

Comment: @Krypt . . . Then you are not actually storing the values you want, but approximations to them.  It is better to store the values you want.